# Shell script Create case statements based on the file names mentioned in a text file

Tags: shell

I have a use case for a shell script, where I want a user to select the files mentioned in a file. That choice can be used to install the selected package using other commands.
I have succeeded to create the list of required files in the directory. 
I need help to populate them in the case choices where the user can select the file and do further actions.
I have used this to write the file for required filename:

```
dir=/root/vaibhav/install_package
> choices
for entry in "$search_dir"$dir/*.zip
do
  echo "$entry" | cut -d "/" -f5 >> choices
done
```

the Output of the choice file is something like this:

```
content_abc.zip
content_xyz_test.zip
content_aacd_to_qa.zip
```

Now i want the script to read this file and convert it int choices where the user can do further action.
This is what i want:

```
case "<read_thefile"
1)<firstLine_from_file>
    Do some actions
;;
2)<secondline_fromfile>
    do some actions
;;
esac
```

Help me in this.

Comment: I have tried to populate the list using the below script, but failing:
for i in `ls -a packages/*.zip`
do
echo $i"," | cut -d"/" -f2 >> files
done
file=`cat files`
OIFS=$IFS;
IFS=", ";
file1=${file};
for ((a=0; a<${#file1[@]}; a++));
do
echo "File $a  --> " ${file1[$a]}
done;
        IFS=$OIFS;`
it gives the output as:
File 0  -->  content_abc.zip
content_xyz_test.zip
content_aacd_to_qa.zip

I want it as :
1. content_abc.zip
2. content_xyz_test.zip
3. content_aacd_to_qa.zip

Also i have no idea how to dynamically populate the choice to perform actions on these files. Help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do two things in your script:

1. generate the `case` (or `select`) switches from a template, write it to a file, and source that file. This could work, but if the input file (list of zips) is unreliable I'd not recommend it.
2. display the list with something like `nl list_of_zips`, then `read` an input from the user and based on that number you can pick the line from the `list_of_zips`, e.g.:

   ```
   nl list_of_zips
   # 1 OUTPUT_LINE1
   # 2 OUTPUT_LINE2
   ### now read the choice
   read choice
   ### and get the choice line from the file
   zip_file_choosen=$(awk "NR==$choice {print ; exit }")
   ### and do what you want with $zip_file_choosen ...
   ```